# Android studio, gradle distribution

Tags: android-studio, gradle

I'm a beginner in developing android applications. The problem that I faced is when I open the Android Studio I get this message: "Could not install Gradle distribution from 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.4.1-all.zip'.I downloaded and installed this file manually (gradle-5.4.1-all.zip). It didn't change anything.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hx2lG.png)

Here is the information about the Android studio that I'm trying to use:
Android Studio 4.1.1
Build #AI-201.8743.12.41.6953283, built on November 4, 2020
Runtime version: 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Windows 10 10.0
GC: ParNew, ConcurrentMarkSweep
Memory: 1237M
Cores: 8
Registry: ide.new.welcome.screen.force=true, external.system.auto.import.disabled=true

Comment: Try running this command to update the wrapper `./gradlew wrapper --gradle-version 6.7.1`. Android Studio 4.1.1 requires at least Gradle 6.5 so 5.4.1 definitely won't work.

Comment: do I have to write this directly to command line

Comment: FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not initialize class org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ReflectionCache

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

Comment: This is what I got when I did it

Comment: There's definitely a problem with your gradle installation, I don't know what exactly. Try running the same command again with the `--stacktrace` option and post the relevant parts here.

Comment: FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not create service of type ScriptPluginFactory using BuildScopeServices.createScriptPluginFactory().
> Could not create service of type CrossBuildFileHashCache using BuildSessionScopeServices.createCrossBuildFileHashCache().

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.internal.service.ServiceCreationException: Could not create service of type ScriptPluginFactory using BuildScopeServices.createScriptPluginFactory().

Answer (score 0):

I could solve it running android studio with sudo:

On OSX, it was

```
cd /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/MacOS
sudo ./studio
```

And, that means the dir ~/.gradle was with admin permissions, so, I remove ~/.gradle dir, and after that I launched Android Studio (normal, without sudo) and It worked, because It installed gradle and build the project from scratch.